# Swift objects not visible only when compiling to a tvOS target

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tvos

So I've got an application with multiple targets, some iOS and some tvOS. It's originally written in Objective-C, but we write any new functionality/code in Swift.

The problem is that when building for a tvOS target, the Swift classes don't get added to the -Swift.h file (the one that is generated when building a project with both Objective-C and Swift source files) properly. Thus, the Objective-C code doesn't recognize the Swift classes, and I get build errors.

The project builds fine, and all Swift classes are visible when building an iOS target.

Do any of you have any idea as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Evidently, even though the system *does* create a -Swift.h file, it won't actually bridge the classes unless the `Objective-C-Bridging-Header.h` has a value pointing to a bridging header in the project, **despite** the fact that the `Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name` plist key had a value. It would generate the Swift bridging header just fine--it just wouldn't actually do any of the bridging.